# Webrtc: What is the difference between onIceConnectionChange and onConnectionChange

Tags: java, android, webrtc, peer

I am develloping an adroid video call app with Webrtc using java. I want to make some stuffs when the connection state of the other peer changes. For example When He's trying to reconnect after loosing connection.
I fount some methods in **PeerConnection.Observer** and I don't know which one should I use and Why.
I found :

** `onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState)` ,

**  `onConnectionChange(PeerConnection.PeerConnectionState newState)`

** and `onIceConnectionReceivingChange`
I need your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[iceConnectionState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceConnectionState): represents the state of the `network/transport` layer connection between the peers. An ICE connection involves checking a bunch of ICE candidate pairs between the two peers in an attempt to find a socket pair the two peers can communicate on. Once the state changes to `connected` then the peers are able to communicate.

[connectionState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/connectionState): builds on top of the `iceConnectionState` and represents the `application` layer connection between the peers. Essentially the connection state is the iceConnection + DTLS. If you don't care about low level details then this is the state to monitor. A `connectionState` of `connected` implies an `iceConnectionState` of `connected`.

`onIceConnectionReceivingChange`: That doesn't seem to be part of the "official" (draft) [WebRTC API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/). It's probably coming from the javascript adapter or library you are using.

Comment: Thanks by pointing out the level of each function in the network. Though I found `onIceConnectionReceivingChange` in  the version **1.0.30039** of webrtc (java) and it seems the SdpObserver implemented this method.

Comment: the native webrtc.org library is not following the w3c specification (which is for javascript) very closely